# How to declare int variables within a for loop?

Tags: java, loops, variables

I want to create 16 different variables named numx, x representing the numbers 1-16. I've tried this loop

```
for (int x = 16; x > 0; x--){
      
    }
```

but I can't figure out what to put inside the loop to make it work. To define each number, I would want `numx = fullNum%10`
followed by

```
fullNum -= numx;
fullNum /= 10;
```

so the loop could move on to the next variable with one less digit (i.e. 16-15, 15-14, 14-13, etc).

Comment: You can't create variables like this.  You can, however, create an `ArrayList` or just a plain old `Array` and store your values in there...

Comment: use an array. thats what they are for

Comment: Ok, I'll try using an array thanks for the help!

Comment: You can't dynamiccaly assign variables in java, however what you can do is assign them by ordering them in Arrays or Lists (or different data structures).

This example shows how to do it using a list:

    List<Integer> myIntList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        Integer myVar = HERE what ever logic you want to assign to the variable;
        myIntList.add(myVar);
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most languages, you can't generate variable names dynamically.

Consider using an array instead:

```
int[] num = new int[16];
for (int x = 16; x > 0; x--){
  num[x] = fullNum % 10
}
```